# Highcharts Gantt / Point Event not firing if clicking on Label

Tags: highcharts

I have a problem with events not working as expected because of labels in front.

I created an event as follows **plotOptions** >> **series** >> **point** >> **events** >> **dblclick** and the idea is that my user double click the milestone/pill and they can get an action (in this case, we load a dialog, but that's is not the problem), the problem we have is that if I display a label on the pill, when they click the label nothing happens, the event fires only if no label is displayed or the pill is bigger than the label and we click on the sides (please view screenshot), I would like to know if there's a way to make the label participate of the event or create a double click event for the labels (if any), this is dynamic chart, with tasks being added/removed/edited, etc...

Thank youf any help you may bring.

please check the following screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you used the `custom-events` plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-custom-events

As specified in the docs, you can also add `dblclick` event to data-labels. For example:

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      dataLabels: {
        events: {
          dblclick: function() {
            console.log('dblclick');
          }
        }
      },
      point: {
        events: {
          dblclick: function() {
            console.log('dblclick');
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t09c5Lzd/

Comment: thank you @ppotaczek it did work perfectly... now when I run this and check for the "event" parameter, a regular event is obtained, how could I get the data of the point that I'm double clicking on? thank you for any info

Comment: Hi @Guillermo Perez, For data-labels you can use `this.point` and for points just `this`. Please check this live example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uswpyz0h/

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I used the approach of doing that in SERIES >> dataLabels >> Events >> and I could not access the point data, nor THIS, what I did is, add a SPAN with an ID that included my data separated by "-", then I read the value from the id on the event data... poor solution but did work or at least did what I was expecting... THANK YOU AGAIN

Comment: I am glad that I could help. I am not sure why the solution with `this` didn't work for you. Maybe you have used an arrow function? I can check if you reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you @ppotaczek ... yes, this happens if the custom event is added under SERIES >> dataLabels >> Events >>, then we dont have access to the point info, if is added in the plot as shown by you, the data is available.

Comment: It seems to work as expected also without `plotOptions` part. Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3hovrz1n/